# 'ON REPLACE CASCADE' in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

Let's say I'm tracking donations for a charity:

```sql
CREATE TABLE people {
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  account_number INTEGER NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE(name),
  UNIQUE(account_number)
};
CREATE TABLE donations {
  donor_id INTEGER NOT NULL
    REFERENCES people(id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  amount FLOAT NOT NULL
};
```

I can guarantee that a person's name and account number are both individually unique.

Sometimes I need to update either a user's name or their account number. I receive data that contains both a name and an account number, one of which will have changed. Because both `name` and `account_number` are individually unique, it shouldn't matter which one has changed - so long as one of them is the same as an existing entry in the table, the correct row will be replaced.

This is my understanding of what will happen if I do this with a `REPLACE` statement. The person in the `people` table will be deleted, along with their referenced donation (because of `ON DELETE CASCADE`), and a new person added with no associated donations:

```sql
people                          donations
| id | name | account_number |  | donor_id | amount |
|----|------|----------------|  |----------|--------|
|  1 | John | 11111111111111 |  |        1 | 100.00 |
|  2 | Mark | 22222222222222 |  |        1 | 200.00 |
                                |        2 | 250.00 |

>>> REPLACE INTO people ( name, account_number ) VALUES ( 'Suzy', 22222222222222 );

people                          donations
| id | name | account_number |  | donor_id | amount |
|----|------|----------------|  |----------|--------|
|  1 | John | 11111111111111 |  |        1 | 100.00 |
|  3 | Suzy | 22222222222222 |  |        1 | 200.00 |
```

How can I ensure that referenced values are propagated correctly? This is my desired end result (where '3' is any `people` ID so long as it matches):

```
people                          donations
| id | name | account_number |  | donor_id | amount |
|----|------|----------------|  |----------|--------|
|  1 | John | 11111111111111 |  |        1 | 100.00 |
|  3 | Suzy | 22222222222222 |  |        1 | 200.00 |
                                |        3 | 250.00 |
```

Comment: *How can I ensure that referenced values are propagated correctly?* You can't. The donations will be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is my understanding of what will happen if I do this with a
> REPLACE statement. The person in the people table will be deleted,
> along with their referenced donation (because of ON DELETE CASCADE),
> and a new person added with no associated donations

Correct, but the referenced donations will be permanently deleted.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=083da1a67a446ecb33e51b6f2c907ddc).

> Sometimes I need to update either a user's name or their account
> number. I receive data that contains both a name and an account
> number, one of which will have changed.

What you can do is a simple `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE people 
SET name = 'Suzy', 
    account_number = 22222222222222
WHERE name = 'Suzy' OR account_number = 22222222222222
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=6157e90432e416d6cb87e948040945b4).